# Generating dynamic key for Agora.io using C#

Tags: c#, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using c#, mvc.

Agora sample github doesn`t have C#.

I can't get any solution to generate dynamic key using C#.

I try too may solution but can't got proper solution.

If any one has experience on Agora.io, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora offers a C# implementation: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp

example of token generation using C#

```
AccessToken token = AccessToke(appID, appCertificate, channelName, uid);
token.AddPrivilege(Privileges.kJoinChannel);
token.AddPrivilege(Privileges.kPublishAudioStream);
token.AddPrivilege(Privileges.kPublishVideoStream);
string token = token.Build();
```

for more info on the `.Build()` function look at [AccessToken.cs](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp/src/AgoraIO/Media/AccessToken.cs) and for more privileges that can be set, take a look at [Privileges.cs](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp/src/AgoraIO/Media/Privileges.cs).

Comment: Thanks dear it helps me a lot.

Comment: do you have any solution to take screenshort. because i am using **getVideoFrame** but it can't works in web.

Comment: Agora does not provide an APIs for screen capture, this is something you would have to implement yourself. Its a fairly common functionality in the web to get the image context of a Div

Comment: Is there any possibility to generate key without **uid**?

Comment: there is no way to generate a token without the uid parameter, but if you use `0` for the uid value it will generate a key that can be used by any uid.

Comment: Hello, I used this code to generate token and generated successfully. but after generate token when join channel using join it return **DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED**

Comment: This is a separate issue. Can you post this as a new question?

Comment: Ok Hermes, Added new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572240/web-agora-io-dynamic-key-expired.  Thanks