# Web Agora.io DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED

Tags: c#, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using c# with mvc.

I used this code to generate token and generated successfully. but after generate token when join channel using **.join()** it return DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED.
I Used "AgoraRTCSDK-3.1.0.js"

I used https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp to generate dynamic token

If any one has experience on Agora.io, please help me.

Sample code is..

```
AccessToken token = new AccessToken(apiKey, appCertificate, channelName, "0");
token.addPrivilege(Privileges.kJoinChannel, _expiredTs);
token.addPrivilege(Privileges.kPublishAudioStream, _expiredTs);
token.addPrivilege(Privileges.kPublishVideoStream, _expiredTs);
string strToken = token.build();

public string build()
    {
        this._messageRawContent = Utils.pack(this.message);
        this._signature = generateSignature(_appCertificate
                , _appId
                , _channelName
                , _uid
                , _messageRawContent);

        this._crcChannelName = Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(this._channelName.GetByteArray());
        this._crcUid = Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(this._uid.GetByteArray());

        PackContent packContent = new PackContent(_signature, _crcChannelName, _crcUid, this._messageRawContent);
        byte[] content = Utils.pack(packContent);
        return getVersion() + this._appId + Utils.base64Encode(content);
    }
```

Comment: What expiry time are you setting for the tokens?

Comment: uint _expiredTs = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you generate a token for Agora applications, you need to keep in mind that the expiration time is calculated as a timestamp (time since 1970) so you need to ensure the the expiration time is set to the `currentTime + expirationTimeInSeconds`.

In the above example you are passing the expiration time as 0 which generates a token that is already considered expired.

consider using:

```js
  // set a expiration time of 1 hour in seconds
  let expireTime = 3600;

  // calculate current time in seconds
  const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  // calculate privilege expire time
  const privilegeExpireTime = currentTime + expireTime;
```

Comment: I followed your instruction, but I am still having issue generating a valid token....Do you know if agora io has been changed anything on their end ? Thank you

Comment: nothing has changed, this same logic still applies. I'd suggest asking a new question with any code that you can provide so the team can help you.

Comment: Can Someone Put The C# forrm of the Above Code?

Comment: @Adarshs take a look at https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp/test/AgoraIO.Tests/AccessTokenTest.cs